# i cant open my android studio AVD with run android command on CLI

Tags: android, react-native, command-line-interface

after i initiated my react native project i install react native globally
npx install -g react-native-cli

i then went to my project directory and created a new react project

npx react-native init MyProject

i then started the react native project
npm start

and the did the run android
run android

and it returned and error not recognize "run"

i tried to uninstall react native globally
npx uninstall -g react-native -cli

and reinstall react native globally
npx install -g react-native-cli

and then start the react native server
npm start

and run android
but it still shows same error

Comment: You should check your system enviroment PATH for sdk, jdk and tools. Then restart your pc for prepare virtualization. after all pls try again.

Answer (score 0):

try running by `npm start run-android` or `npx react-native run-android`

or you can see more information here: [Click here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device)